# Maximum Value from multiple tables

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am a high school math teacher and my school's "data specialist."  I am self-taught in Microsft Exel and Access, and I have been recently learning some of the SQL query language behind my usual Access work.  I am comfortable with using Access queries to tie together data from many sources, such as exam scores from one source, English proficiency from a second source, and home phone number from a third source.

Here is a situation that I do not know how to do in Microsoft Access.

My math students take the New York state examination up to 3 times a year.  They need a score of 80 to be considered "college ready."

Here are 3 sample tables.  Each table uses the unique primary key "StudentID."  The Integrated Algebra exam has the code MXRE.

```
Table #1 name:  JanuaryAlgebra

StudentID   Course    Mark    
201          MXRE      90 
202          MXRE      55
203          MXRE      67
204          MXRE      80
205          MXRE      78
```

Note:  Student #201 and #204 have finished the exam and do not take it again.

```
Table #2 name:  JuneAlgebra

StudentID   Course    Mark
202          MXRE      70
203          MXRE      76
205          MXRE      81
206          MXRE      86
207          MXRE      78
```

There are two new students to the school, #206 and #207.  Students #205 and #206 have finished the exam with high scores, and the remaining three students try the exam a third time.

Table #3 name:  AugustAlgebra

```
StudentID   Course    Mark
202          MXRE      72
203          MXRE      83
207          MXRE      93
```

How do I return a query with one line for each StudentID displaying their highest exam score after the end of the school year???

Thanks!

- Jeff

Comment: I don't think you can do this in one Access query (unless you have another table with all the student ids).  Have you considered switching to another database such as SQL Server Express (also free)?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not as familiar with Access, but I think it supports T-SQL.  If it does then you can select all the rows in one statement and get the max. Though I realized when writing this answer that it's probably easier with a sub-select

In SQL it would look something like:

```
SELECT StudentId, Course, Max(Mark)
FROM (
   SELECT StudentId, Course, Mark FROM JanuaryAlgebra
   UNION
   SELECT StudentId, Course, Mark FROM JuneAlgebra
   UNION 
   SELECT StudentId, Course, Mark FROM AugustAlgebra
) as NewTable
GROUP BY StudentId, Course
```

Comment: For the record, Access SQL and T-SQL (for SQL Server) are very different, but the query in your answer should work okay in Access SQL.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest altering the table structure:

```
YourTable (Student_ID,Course,Mark,Date)
```

Then you can simply query:

```
SELECT Student_ID,Course,MAX(Mark) AS Max_Mark
FROM YourTable
--WHERE Course = 'MXRE'    --If you wanted only algebra results.
GROUP BY Student_ID,Course
```

Multiple tables of identical structure almost never makes sense.

You can however use your current format to do this by unioning together all your tables in a subquery.